# How to display values with decimal places in Grafana with elasticsearch datasource?

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I am trying to visualize time series data stored in elastic search using grafana.
I have the legend setup to show 2 decimal places but it does not reflect in the UI.

The decimal places show up for other dashboard panels with a tsdb datasource. So this issue is specific to using grafana with elasticsearch. Is there any other configuration setup I am missing here which will help me achieve this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just found out that elastic search does not allow displaying values without some sort of aggregation and in my case aggregation is resulting in values getting rounded.

There was a related request which seemed to not get much traction in kibana.
https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3572

In short not feasible as of [2.x] elastic search.